# System will not shut down or reboot on Asus notebook

Tags: shutdown, laptop, asus, systemd, reboot

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit

Kernel: 5.13.0-27-generic

Gnome version: 3.36.8

Hardware: Asus Q406D 2-in-1 Notebook PC

I've encountered this problem only in the last few days. When I attempt to shut down the PC from the "Power off/log out" option, the system displays the following: `Finished power off. Reached target power off` and the cursor is blinking at the bottom of the screen, but the system will not power off until I force shut down by holding the power button.

Similarly, when trying to reboot the system, the following is displayed: `Finished reboot. Reached target reboot` And below that, the following message is displayed:

`44.839658] systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: systemd-udevd,systemd-udevd`

`63.867419] systemd-udevd[353]: 0000:02:00.7: Worker [366] processing SEQNUM=2908 is taking a long time`

There is a cursor at the bottom, and the system stays here until I force shut down by holding the power button. Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite a fix for your problem, but have you tried to shut down your machine with ```$ sudo shutdown now``` or the ```$ poweroff``` commands? You can finde some additional information on them [here](https://www.tecmint.com/shutdown-poweroff-halt-and-reboot-commands-in-linux). This may be a better way then force power off every time.

Comment: Yes, I tried both `$ sudo shutdown now` and `$ poweroff` but both ended with the same result: the system would not power off and there was a message that said `systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: systemd-udevd,systemd-udevd`

Comment: I have the same problem when switched the Nvidia graphics driver to the 525-open-kernel-tested version.

Answer (score 1):

OS: Lubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit

Kernel: 5.13.0-27-generic

Hardware: Asus PN50-E1 SFF PC based on AMD Ryzen 4700

I had the same issue on an Asus PN50 which, like the Q406, is an AMD Ryzen based PC (I think there is a theme here).  I also updated the kernel to clear the issue but for security reasons I was not comfortable using scripts or ppa packages from the Internet, even though they are well respected sources.

I would not call myself an expert, but this is what I did using commands in a terminal window (Ctrl-Alt-t).  First, I made sure everything was up to date using the following command line that updates and upgrades everything:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
```

Next I found out what my current kernel version was by using:

```
uname -r
```

My version with the issue was 5.13.0-27-generic (after an ugrade from 5.11 which was working fine).  Next I found the latest oem package for the linux kernel that matched my linux release (20.04) using the following command line:

```
sudo apt list linux-oem-20.04*
```

This gave me a list similar to this:

```
linux-oem-20.04-edge/focal-updates,focal-security 5.10.0.1057.57 amd64
linux-oem-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.10.0.1057.57 amd64
linux-oem-20.04b/focal-updates,focal-security 5.10.0.1057.57 amd64
linux-oem-20.04c/focal-updates,focal-security 5.13.0.1028.30 amd64
linux-oem-20.04d/focal-updates,focal-security 5.14.0.1020.17 amd64
```

where the last part of each entry is the kernel version.  So I chose to install the 5.14 kernel as follows:

```
sudo apt install -y linux-oem-20.04d
```

Once this had finished, I shut down (hopefully for the last time with the annoying power-off button being required)

```
shutdown now
```

Finally, I rebooted, signed in, opened the terminal window, and ran three more commands to clean up and check which kernel I had:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt -y autoremove
uname -r
```

I now have kernel 5.14.0-1020-oem which shuts down and reboots as my old version of kernel did.

If someone knows what I have described above is not a good thing to do then please reply.

Thanks to #Ramza and #Fatrobin for getting me on the right path out of this issue.

Comment: I did not get a chance to try your fix, however, I can confirm that as of Kernel update 5.13.0-28-generic, my system is now able to shut down again like normal.